# The console shows an "lnvariant Violation" error, but only on one page. What could be the cause?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[This is the dreaded error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbjp2.png)

After browsing other questions who encountered the "Invariant Error", it looks like a configuration issue. However, I only get this error on one page and the other pages are functional. It's a page where the user checks some checkboxes. These are functional, but after hitting a "Save" button, the changes don't save.

Here are the the index, root, webpack files in case you notice something wrong:

webpack:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: {
    app: [ 'babel-polyfill', './src/index.js' ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].min.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: ''
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new dotenv({path: __dirname + '/.envp'}),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        "process.env": JSON.stringify(dotenv.parsed),
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
        'process.env.BABEL_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
      }
    ),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compressor: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('app.css', { allChunks: true }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'index.template.html',
      favicon: path.join(__dirname, 'src/assets/images/favicon.ico')
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel', include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
      },
      {
          test: /\.css$/,
          loader: 'style!css?modules&localIdentName=[name]__[local__[hash:base64:8]&importLoaders=1!postcss'
      },
      {
          test: /\.json$/,
          loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
          test: /\.png|ttf|woff2|woff$/,
          loader: 'file-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: "style!css!postcss!less"
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.css', '.png', '.woff', '.woff2', '.ttf']
  },
  cssnext: {
    browsers: 'last 2 versions'
  }
};
```

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "config": {
    "color": "always"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm run clean && webpack --config webpack.config.qa.js",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "dist": "npm run clean && webpack --config webpack.config.production.js",
    "qadist": "npm run clean && webpack --config webpack.config.qa.js",
    "start": "npm run build && node server.js --progress ",
    "start:dev": "npm run clean && webpack --config webpack.config.js && node server.js --progress ",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/dotenv": "^6.1.1",
    "@types/dotenv-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "@types/html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.1",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^2.2.4",
    "@types/universal-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "classnames": "~2.2.3",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "glob": "^6.0.4",
    "history": "~1.17.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^1.7.0",
    "intl": "~1.0.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "parse-link-header": "~0.4.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "purecss": "~0.6.0",
    "rc-tooltip": "^3.3.2",
    "react": "~0.14.9",
    "react-datepicker": "^0.27.0",
    "react-dom": "~0.14.6",
    "react-dropzone": "^3.13.1",
    "react-intl": "2.0.0-beta-1",
    "react-modal": "~1.3.0",
    "react-redux": "~4.0.6",
    "react-router": "~1.0.3",
    "react-search-input": "^0.8.1",
    "react-transform-catch-errors": "^1.0.1",
    "react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.1",
    "redbox-react": "^1.2.0",
    "redux": "~3.0.5",
    "redux-promise-middleware": "^3.0.0",
    "redux-router": "~1.0.0-beta7",
    "universal-cookie": "^2.0.7",
    "webpack": "^1.12.10",
    "whatwg-fetch": "~0.10.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^5.0.0-beta6",
    "babel-plugin-react-intl": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.4.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "cssnext-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "dateformat": "^1.0.12",
    "eslint": "^1.10.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^3.14.0",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.7",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.4.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.6.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "less": "^2.6.1",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "lodash.assign": "^4.2.0",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.13.0",
    "moment-range": "^2.2.0",
    "normalize.css": "^4.1.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.0.1"
  }
}
```

index.js file:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import Root, { store } from './Root'
import { addLocaleData } from 'react-intl'
import en from 'react-intl'

addLocaleData(en)

// All modern browsers, except `Safari`, have implemented
// the `ECMAScript Internationalization API`.
start()

function start () {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Root />
    </Provider>
  , document.getElementById('app'))
}
```

And finally, the Root.js file:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import { ReduxRouter } from 'redux-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { IntlProvider } from 'react-intl';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
import configureStore from './utils/configure-store'
import { getCookieDomain } from './utils/domain';
import * as storage from './persistence/storage'
import * as containers from './containers'
import * as ActionTypes from './constants/ActionTypes'
import cookiefetch  from './utils/userutils';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


const cookie = new Cookies();
const {
  Admin,
  AdminCreateAccount,
  AdminUser,
  Companies,
  Users,
  Application,
  ForgotPassword,
  Login,
  Profile,
  ResetPassword,
  UpdatePassword,
  ReleaseNotes,
  Success,
} = containers

const cookieDomain = getCookieDomain();

const initialState = {
  application: {
    token: storage.get('token'),
    locale: storage.get('locale') || 'en',
    user: { permissions: [/*'manage_account'*/] }
  }
}

export const store = configureStore(initialState)

function getRootChildren (props) {
  const intlData = {
    locale: props.application.locale
  }
  const rootChildren = [
    <IntlProvider key="intl" {...intlData}>
      {renderRoutes()}
    </IntlProvider>
  ]


  return rootChildren
}


function renderRoutes () {
  return (
    <ReduxRouter>
      <Route component={Application}>
        <Route path="/" component={Profile} onEnter={requireAuth}/>
        <Route path="admin" component={Admin} onEnter={requireAdminAuth}>
          <Route path="companies" component={Companies} onEnter={requireAdminAuth}/>
          <Route path="users" component={Users}/>
          <Route path="release-notes" component={ReleaseNotes}/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="forgot-password" component={ForgotPassword} />
        <Route path="login" component={Login} onEnter={removeCookies} />
        <Route path="logout" onEnter={removeCookies} />
        <Route path="profile" component={Profile} onEnter={requireAuth}/>
        <Route path="update-password" component={UpdatePassword} />
        <Route path="success" component={Success} />
        <Route path="reset-password" component={ResetPassword}/>
      </Route>
    </ReduxRouter>
  )
}

function requireAuth (nextState, replaceState) {
  // removeProdCookies();
  const state = store.getState()
  const tokenCookie = cookiefetch('token','');
  const userId = cookiefetch('userId','');
  var role = cookiefetch('role','');
  role = (role != '') ? role.toLowerCase() : '';
  var isLoggedIn = (tokenCookie === '' || userId === '' || role === '') ? false : true;
  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    var url = '/login' + nextState.location.search;
    replaceState({
      nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname
    }, url)
  }
}

function requireAdminAuth (nextState, replaceState) {

  const tokenCookie = cookiefetch('token','');
  const userid = cookiefetch('userId','');
  var role = cookiefetch('role','');
  role = (role != '') ? role.toLowerCase() : '';
  var isLoggedIn = (tokenCookie === '' || userid === '' || role === '') ? false : true;
  var isAdmin = (role === 'administrator' || role === 'adminread') ? true : false;
  if (!isLoggedIn || !isAdmin ) {
    var url = '/login' + nextState.location.search;
    replaceState({
      nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname
    }, url)
  }
}

function requireAdminOwnerAuth (nextState, replaceState) {
  const tokenCookie = cookiefetch('token','');
  const userIdCookie = cookiefetch('userId','');
  var role = cookiefetch('role','');
  role = (role != '') ? role.toLowerCase() : '';
  var isLoggedIn = (tokenCookie === '' || userIdCookie === '' || role === '') ? false : true;
  var isAdmin = (role === 'administrator' || role === 'owner' || role === 'adminread') ? true : false;
  if (!isLoggedIn || !isAdmin) {
    var url = '/login' + nextState.location.search;
    replaceState({
      nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname
    }, url)
  }
}

function logout (nextState, replaceState) {
  window.localStorage.clear();
  removeProdCookies();
  replaceState({}, '/login')
}

function removeCookies (nextState, replaceState) {
  var all = cookie.getAll();
  for (var key in all) {
    if (key == 'redirectDomain') {
      continue;
    }
    cookie.remove(key, {domain: cookieDomain});
  }
  removeProdCookies();
}

function removeProdCookies() {

  var leftOverCookies = cookie.getAll();
  for (var key in leftOverCookies) {
    if (key == 'redirectDomain') {
      continue;
    }
    cookie.remove(key, {domain: "myappdomain.com"});
  }
}

class Root extends React.Component {

  static propTypes = {
    application: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };
  render () {
    return (
      <div>{getRootChildren(this.props)}</div>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(({ application }) => ({ application }))(Root)
```

Is there something wrong with the configuration/versioning. Why am I getting the Invariant error?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is too much code. Can you minimize the problem? That is, show the shortest amount of code necessary to reproduce it. See [mcve]. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! I think these are the files where the problems could be happening. I'm not sure I can pinpoint the culprit.

Comment: The link above says "The more code there is to go through, the less likely people can find your problem". So if you're unwilling to debug/minimize, likely nobody else will be willing to either. In general, large dumps of code don't have much usefulness to future visitors because the problem-solution pair is unclear. Surely, most of this code is totally irrelevant to the underlying problem you're asking about and only obfuscates the question.